# Rails Unit::Test error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

This is my first day in Rails testing, I've got a working project but haven't added any tests at all. First of all I wanted to `rake` to see if everything is working (for a good start), but...

```
    [37/38] UsermailerTest#test_notifyadmin = 0.00 s              
    25) Error:
    test_notifyadmin(UsermailerTest):
    NameError: uninitialized constant UsermailerTest::Usermailer
        /Users/linus/Documents/Work/Coding/Rails/project/test/functional/usermailer_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:UsermailerTest>'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1301:in `run'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit/testcase.rb:17:in `run'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:36:in `block in run'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `_run__1175861498219140925__setup__3741829296426871776__callbacks'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in `run'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:919:in `block in _run_suite'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:912:in `map'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:912:in `_run_suite'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:657:in `block in _run_suites'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:655:in `each'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:655:in `_run_suites'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:867:in `_run_anything'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1060:in `run_tests'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1047:in `block in _run'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1046:in `each'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1046:in `_run'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1035:in `run'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:21:in `run'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:774:in `run'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:366:in `block (2 levels) in autorun'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:27:in `run_once'
        /Users/linus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:365:in `block in autorun'

    [38/38] UsersControllerTest#test_should_get_show = 0.00 s
     26) Failure:
    test_should_get_show(UsersControllerTest) [/Users/linus/Documents/Work/Coding/Rails/project/test/functional/users_controller_test.rb:6]:
    Expected response to be a <:success>, but was <302>

    Finished tests in 0.763938s, 49.7423 tests/s, 27.4891 assertions/s.
    38 tests, 21 assertions, 8 failures, 18 errors, 0 skips

    ruby -v: ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
    Errors running test:functionals! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (26): [ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib" "/Users/linus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/functional/**/*_test.rb" ]>
```

I have absolutely no clue what is wrong here (new territory for me), where it is coming from or how I can fix it so I really hope someone can help. I'm usind devise for user management if that is important.

Note: This error above isn't the only one, there are 'many' of them, all beginning nearly the same, so I thought I just add one for clarity reasons.

```
[37/38] UsermailerTest#test_notifyadmin = 0.00 s              
        25) Error:
        test_notifyadmin(UsermailerTest):
        NameError: uninitialized constant UsermailerTest::Usermailer
```

and so on...

**Update**

Here is the code from test/functional/usermailer_test.rb

require 'test_helper'

```
class UsermailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  test "notifyadmin" do
    mail = Usermailer.notifyadmin
    assert_equal "Notifyadmin", mail.subject
    assert_equal ["to@example.org"], mail.to
    assert_equal ["from@example.com"], mail.from
    assert_match "Hi", mail.body.encoded
  end

end
```

Comment: "I've got a working project but haven't added any tests at all." Then you don't have a working project. Anyway, what does the code in `test/functional/usermailer_test.rb` look like?

Comment: I added the code as an update to my question.

Comment: Maybe I can provide any additional info?

Comment: What does `Usermailer` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there were 2 versions of some testing controllers. Some were named plural, some singular. The singular named controllers led to error messages, as they are not up to date with the last changes I made to the mvc controllers. Additionally, I renamed some controllers like Usermailer to UserMailer, which led to the issue they couldn't be found.